# How to make store expression for entity framework?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-5

Let say i have query like this

```
context.MyClass.ListSubClasses.Sum(x=> x.UseNetPrice ? x.NetPrice : x.TotalPrice);
```

This is just example my lamda expression im much more complicated and I use it on several places.
What I want to do is

```
context.MyClass.ListSubCalsses.Sum(x=>x.Price());
```

And my method is:

```
public static double? Price(IQueryable<MyClass> class)
    { return class.Select(x=> x.UseNetPrice ? x.NetPrice : x.TotalPrice);}
```

I am getting error.
Can you help me with an example how to write store expression?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to create the full lambda expression in a helper method and then just retun the expresion.

So, then you do:

```
context.YourEntities.Where(HelperClass.GetPricePredicate());
```

Your `GetPricePredicate()` can be something like:

```
public Expression<Func<YourEntity, bool>> GetPricePredicate()
{ 
    var myPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<YourEntity>();
    myPredicate = myPredicate.And(y => y.idTenant == tenantID);
    myPredicate = myPredicate.And(y => y.idCategory == 1);

    return myPredicate;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but there is much more calculation involved and it should return double not bool.

Comment: So, instead of returning just the expression (this method just returns the expression, you use and do the query after that) you can receive the list of items as a parameter and do the calculation... do this complex thing in a method and use it any time you need it. But don't mess with the expressions and extensions in the lambda... it gets complex very soon.